# Arbitrary Data Points to Known UTMs

Tags: arcmap, utm, arcgis-10.6

I have a series of data points that are placed out along an arbitrary grid and I have the known UTM of the datum for this grid.

I'm sure there is a way to snap all the arbitrary points so they are placed out in real UTMs based on the known UTM of the datum, but because it's early in the morning and I haven't had my coffee yet, I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: I am sorry, but I do not understand what you mean by UTM or datum. Can you please give some examples of actual numeric values that you are using?

Comment: Check out the spatial adjustment toolbar.